# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement - Call procedure inside another

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I create procedure which call procedure inside another. I have an error ***ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AP_MOVE_OUT
is
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'AP_MOVEOUT_COUNT(''GNW-M2'',to_date(''2020-11-02'',''yyyy-MM-dd''),to_date(''2020-11-06'',''yyyy-MM-dd''),''ast'');';
END;
/
```

Procedure compiled without any error, but when I run it:

```
BEGIN 
  AP_MOVE_OUT;
END;
/
```

I've got an error: **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at "DEVUSER.AP_MOVE", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"**

When I execute procedure AP_MOVEOUT_COUNT outside procedure AP_MOVE_OUT it works correctly, so I can't find the reason of these error. Here is the example that works for me outside procedure AP_MOVE_OUT:

```
EXEC AT_MOVEOUT_COUNT('GNW-M2',to_date('2020-11-02','yyyy-MM-dd'),to_date('2020-11-06','yyyy-MM-dd'),'ast');
```

Answer (score 2):

Expression called by `execute immediate` should be a valid `sql` or `pl/sql` statement. In your case the statement is not complete. Transforming it to a complete anonymous `pl/sql block` should solve the problem.

```sql
create or replace procedure AP_MOVE_OUT
is
BEGIN 
  execute immediate 'begin AP_MOVEOUT_COUNT(''GNW-M2'',to_date(''2020-11-02'',''yyyy-MM-dd''),to_date(''2020-11-06'',''yyyy-MM-dd''),''ast''); end;';
END;
```

See also simple example on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4c5e1ef85de8b418999c524f99ee943)

Also consider using bind variables instead of concatenating values into the code.

Comment: Do you really need nested begin/end statements?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think yes. If you want to use dynamic statement and so avoid the hard dependency - you need to have a valid pl/sql block inside.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to call a stored procedure from another.  You also don't use `EXEC` or any other keyword.

You've said that

```sql
exec AT_MOVEOUT_COUNT('GNW-M2',to_date('2020-11-02','yyyy-MM-dd'),to_date('2020-11-06','yyyy-MM-dd'),'ast');
```

works, so I would expect the following procedure to work too:

```sql
create or replace procedure AP_MOVE_OUT
is
BEGIN
  AT_MOVEOUT_COUNT('GNW-M2',to_date('2020-11-02','yyyy-MM-dd'),to_date('2020-11-06','yyyy-MM-dd'),'ast');
END;
```